# ImageContents not working on Wolfram Cloud iOS app

Tags: wolfram-cloud, version-12, computer-vision

I tried using the experimental `ImageContents[]` function, introduced in MMA 12, on my PC (using Mathematica) as well as on my iPad (using Wolfram Cloud app). On my PC it worked, but not on Wolfram Cloud. It said that it had to download some 200 MB of data from their servers, just like it did on Mathematica. However after the download nothing happened.

This was the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Fd4n.jpg

And this is the result on my PC: [image: ImageContents results]

Does anyone know what is the issue?